# How does the hash function for a tuple work

Tags: python, hash

According to my understanding in Python, since tuples are immutable they should be hashable and the `hash()` function should work on them. However seems like this is not the case because when they contain items such as lists or dicts, then the hash function complains as shown below.

This works:

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 'name', 'Subhayan', 'age', 32, 'sex', 'male')
>>> hash(t)
3584505648807432737
```

This does not work:

```
>>> t = ({'First': 1, 'second': 2}, 'age', 32, 'sex', 'male', 'name', 'Subhayan')
>>> hash(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

So my question is how does hash function internally operate? Does it loop through the tuple and try to hash the individual components?

Can someone please give me some references on how this works.

Comment: If a tuple contains a mutable object it **must not** be hashable. It can change its hash value rendering most implementations that rely on hash functions useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the hash for immutable containers take the hashes of the contained objects.

For tuples see the `Objects/tupleobject.c` source code, specifically the  [`tuplehash` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/tupleobject.c#L336-L369):

```c
static Py_hash_t
tuplehash(PyTupleObject *v)
{
    Py_uhash_t x;  /* Unsigned for defined overflow behavior. */
    Py_hash_t y;
    Py_ssize_t len = Py_SIZE(v);
    PyObject **p;
    Py_uhash_t mult = _PyHASH_MULTIPLIER;
    x = 0x345678UL;
    p = v->ob_item;
    while (--len >= 0) {
        y = PyObject_Hash(*p++);
        if (y == -1)
            return -1;
        x = (x ^ y) * mult;
        /* the cast might truncate len; that doesn't change hash stability */
        mult += (Py_hash_t)(82520UL + len + len);
    }
    x += 97531UL;
    if (x == (Py_uhash_t)-1)
        x = -2;
    return x;
}
```

In Python, ignoring C int type overflows, the equivalent would be:

```
_PyHASH_MULTIPLIER = 1000003  # from pyhash.h

def tuplehash(v):
    x = 0x345678
    mult = _PyHASH_MULTIPLIER
    l = len(v)
    for i, ob in enumerate(v, 1):
        y = hash(ob)
        x = ((x ^ y) * mult)
        mult += (82520 + 2 * (l - i))
    x += 97531
    return x
```

The 'magic numbers' are there to ensure that the tuple hash produces a wide range of values for small changes in the content hashes.

That's the most logical implementation after all; the hash should reflect the values contained, and when you test for equality against another tuple, the contained values are tested against the objects in the other tuple too; the hash and equality functionality are closely related.

Tuples can reference any type of object; the tuple itself cannot be altered but that doesn’t mean you can’t alter the objects that are refenced by it. This, the hashability of tuples depends on the hashability of the objects the tuple references.

Comment: Shouldn't be there an "l = l - 1" in the loop of Python's implementation?

Comment: @jianchang: the `len` variable is decremented: `--len`, which, come to think of it, I forgot about in my Python version. I’ve corrected that error now.